Selecting appropriate Opamp for RRO applications
I am designing a circuit which is intended to map a signal in the 0-5V range to the 1.75-7.0V range. To do this I am using an LM317T voltage regulator in conjunction with a TLC2272 Rail-to-Rail opamp. After testing the circuit in LTSpice, I got promising results with the output behaving as expected:

However, after getting my hands on an actual TLC2272 and building the circuit I get the following voltage clamping:

For reference, Ch1 is monitoring input voltage and Ch2 is monitoring the TLC2272 output. From what I can gather the waveform is being clipped because the TLC2272 is not equipped to handle my application. My question is, how do I avoid this in the future? What spec should I pay attention to on the op-amp datasheets to avoid this?
As a replacement I am looking at the OPA2991 or the TLV9152. Would these be better candidates?
Edit: After increasing all opamp resistor values by 10x as per @Spehro Pefhany's suggestion, the opamp is functioning as expected with a 0-5V signal:


Why are you even using an LM317? Please explain that. Please edit the question to add specifications for the output. At the very least: maximum output frequency, and load current(s) and what quadrants should the output stage be driving the load.

Your resistor values are very low. Try increasing them by an order of magnitude (10x). Consider this figure from the datasheet:

Even with nothing connected to the output, the op-amp will have to source more than 3mA just to get to 6.5V out. Which it can barely do. Typically, not guaranteed. Which is what you are seeing.

I can confirm this for the TLC2272 or TLC2274, it shows even in simulation. With two 1k resistors in the feedback there is positive clipping at ~6.1V, with two 10k resistors the output voltage is as it should be. Interesting to see that with the TLC272 or TLC274 there isn't any clipping with the heavier load.

@JaysonOkhman Don’t edit the question with more questions after it’s been answered. Instead, post a new question and link to the old question (if applicable).

@SteKulov Apologies, new to StackExchange. I removed the edit.

This is the kind of investigation and discovery that can be very helpful in the future, in a way that blindly replacing the op-amp with one that happens to have a higher output current capability would not be. When one sees marketing terms like "rail-to-rail" and "zero drift", one should ask what are the real limitations and what bad effects might come along with the good. And read the datasheet (particularly the numbers, and how they ware specified) and check the typical performance, both with a jaundiced eye.

Even so they sometimes try to hide bad behaviour from the reader (for example by choosing graph limits and points where performance is specified to avoid areas where the part does something unpleasant and probably unexpected to the user).

The basic circuit consists of two parts:

Summer that adds an offset voltage.
Gain stage.

The summer takes the average of two input voltages, so it divides by two. We can now find the required offset and gain:
$$\begin{equation}
\rm{gain} \overbrace{ \frac{0{\rm\,V}+{\rm offset}}{2} }^{\rm SUM} = 
          \overbrace{ 1.75{\rm\,V} }^{\rm OUT}, \\
\rm{gain} \frac{5{\rm\,V}+{\rm offset}}{2} = 7.00{\rm\,V}. \\
\end{equation}$$
The solution of this system is \${\rm gain}=2.1\$, \${\rm offset}=1\frac{6}{9}{\rm\,V}\$.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The offset voltage can be obtained by a resistive divider with Thevenin resistance equal to that of R2. We can now scale the circuit to E96 resistance values (1% resistors), and add two trimmers to adjust gain and offset:

simulate this circuit
The circuit will be close to desired transfer function with both trimmers centered. Necessary adjustments will be within about 1/2 of trimmer range.
If your 12V supply is not well regulated, then you'll need a better source of offset voltage. The ubiquitous TL[V]431 will do a fine job - much better than LM317T.

The TLC2272 is marketed as a "rail-to-rail" op-amp, ie: "Output Swing Includes Both Supply Rails".  Also the inputs can swing very close to the supply rails, refer fig 12 of the datasheet:

So in theory, if your protoype circuit matches the sim, then it should be working.
Some sanity checks:

Are you sure that VCC on the op-amp (pin 8 on the 8-pin package) is +12V (at least over 8V), and not, say, 5.5V?
Is your power supply going into current-limit?
What load is connected to the op-amp output that is not shown in the sim?
With the signal source set to 0V (shorted to GND), what is the output of the op-amp?



Yes I am sure VCC is 12V, it is being power by a dedicated 12V wall adapter, 2) No, the wall adapter is rated for 3A. 3) Currently, no load other than the oscilloscope probe, essentially a high impedance load. The final application of the device will also be a high-impedance load. 4) with the signal set to 0V, the circuit behaves as expected and gives me ~1.75V which matches my simulations.


Noted. What are waveforms at both inputs of opamp under same test conditions as per your first scope image?
